# MySQL: ignore constraint within SQL transaction

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, constraints

For a collection with [multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529207/restful-patch-on-collection-to-update-sorting-parameter-in-bulk) I want to update the ordering of the items. In MySQL I have a constraint that (order + collection_id) is unique. So, you cannot have two items at order 1 in the same collection.

However, now I want to update the ordering of items "atomically". For my ORM, I updated all entities with the new order and performed a flush to write them down into the database. The ORM converts them into multiple queries and this directly results in a constraint violation from MySQL.

**Example:**

I have items in order A, B, C. So A=1, B=2 and C=3. Then I perform the update with order C, B, A. So C=1, B=2, A=1. These are two queries and the first update directly runs into a constraint violation. In pseudo:

```
UPDATE item SET order=1 WHERE id=C
```

**My idea**

Is it possible to start a transaction, remove the constraint, then apply all changes and enable the constraint again? If the enabling fails, the rollback will ensure everything is set back.

**Alternative**

An alternative is to remove the constraint altogether, but I am not very fond of the solution :)

Comment: Short answer: No. Schema alterations aren't protected by transactions. They're global.

Comment: Try a two pass approach.  Cycle once and set the orders to their negative values and flush then cycle again and set the orders to their new values.  Don't try fooling with the constraint.  Nothing good can come of it.

Comment: @Cerad great idea, will test it out but it will definitely work :-)